# Unable to setup Azure alert on resource specific events

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-monitoring, azure-eventgrid

In the past, it was possible to setup an Azure alert on a single event for a resource e.g. on data factory single RunFinished where the status is Failed*.

This appears to have been [superseded by "Activity Log Alerts"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-migrate-management-alerts)

However these alerts only seem to either work on a metric threshold (e.g. number of failures in 5 minutes) or on events which are related to the general admin of the resource (e.g. has it been deployed) not on the operations of the resource.

A threshold doesn't make sense for data factory, as a data factory may only run once a day, if a failure happens and then it doesn't happen X minutes later it doesn't mean it's been resolved.

The activity event alerts, don't seem to have things like failures.

Am I missing something?

It it because this is expected to be done in OMS Log Analytics now? Or perhaps even in Event Grid later?

*n.b. it is still possible to create these alert types via ARM templates, but you can't see them in the portal anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The events you're describing are part of a resource type's diagnostic logs, which are not alertable in the same way that the Activity Log is. I suggest routing the data to Log Analytics and setting the alert there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor

Comment: Thanks John I was thinking a similar thing, does this mean that built in event style logging is being deprecated? I could only see log analytics alerts for thresholds, rather than one of triggers. Unless the idea is that this is done in OMS or stream analytics instead now (though seems a little overkill)?